# ¿Cómo puedo obtener la última fila mediante Foreign key?

Tags: python, django

Tengo dos `models`, están relacionados mediante un Foreign Key

```
class Categorias(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=25)

class Posts(models.Model):
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Título")
    categoria = models.ForeignKey(Categorias, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fecha = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Fecha de creación")
```

¿Cómo puedo obtener el último post de las categorías?

Comment: El último post de acuerdo a qué? Me parece que te falta incluir un campo en `Post` que sea la fecha de creación, ¿no?

Comment: @revliscano Sí, perdona, ya está editado, es de acuerdo a la fecha de creación

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La Queryset API de Django contempla un método para conseguir, justamente, lo que deseas.

Me refiero a `latest()`*, el cual recibe como argumento el campo con respecto al cual quieras obtener el registro más reciente, y devuelve dicho objeto.

En tu caso, el código sería:

```
latest_post = Posts.objects.latest('fecha')
```

Si deseas obtener el último post añadido de una categoría en particular, puedes hacerlo incluyendo `filter()` antes de `latest()`. Por ejemplo:

```
politics = Categorias.objects.get(nombre='Politics')
latest_politics_post = (
    Posts.objects
    .filter(categoria=politics)
    .latest('fecha')
)
```

Por cierto, te sugiero que cambies el nombre de `Posts` a `Post` y `Categorias` a `Categoria` (singular y no plural), como es recomendado por Django.

---

**ciertas condiciones aplican al uso de este método. Puedes leer más acerca de ellas en [la documentación](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#latest)*